# (Actionscript 2.0) Passing a MovieClip to an external script. How to clean up

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, movieclip

I've created a class that contains all of the movie clips from the stage. These variables are referring to the instance's name on the stage. Everything seems fine as long as I keep all of my functionality in a single class. However, when I try to use another class to manage the properties of a movie clip, I run into resource clean up issues.

```
//File (MainScreen.as)
import utils.Container;

class MainScreen extends MovieClip
{
    private var clip1:MovieClip;
    private var clip2:MovieClip;
    private var container:Container

    public function MainScreen()
    {
        container = new Container(clip1);
    }

    public function CleanUpMess()
    {
        container.CleanUpMess(); // <-- This part seems fine

        //? <-- Should I be calling other things here?
    }
}
```

I believe it's related to the assignment shown below **mClip = clip** I want to pass this movie by reference to be used by the Container class but I believe the garbage collector is getting confused when there are two references to the same MovieClip. Is there a way I can give it a hit that this reference is no longer needed.

```
//File (Container.as)
class utils.Container
{
    private var mClip:MovieClip;
    public function Container(clip:MovieClip)
    {
        mClip = clip;
    }

    public function CleanUpMess()
    {
        mClip.removeMovieClip(); // <--- Doesn't seem to work
        removeMovieClip(mClip); // <--- Doesn't seem to work
    }
}
```

I've found **MovieClip.removeMovieClip()** in the Actionscript 2.0 documentation, but I think I'm using it incorrectly, or that it doesn't apply to my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are calling `container.CleanUpMess();` you don't need to set up anything else in that class unless it is not within the `CleanUpMess()` function in the class file. the `CleanUpMess()` method is in the class and therefore has access to the movieclip you passed in to the constructor method. you should be able to just call the movie clip variable in the class file and change its properties from there.

ex:

```
public function CleanUpMess()
{
mClip.x = 10;
mClip.y = 30;
}
```

does that help at all?

Comment: I think my question may have been a little confusing, I'll update it. However, this part is interesting... "you might be running into issues where the class that is not attached to the stage doesn't recognize the stage and you can't remove items from the stage from that custom class." do external classes need to be attached to the stage to call clean-up functions?

Comment: yes you can delete instances of the objects that the class made in your MainScreen.as but since the MainScreen is the one document class I assume with direct contact with the stage, you can reference the stage from there.  And sorry if I misunderstood your question I'll try to help you out again when you update it

Comment: No, sorry. I believe what I'm having trouble with is instances of MovieClips being left in memory when MainScreen is terminated. I understand the principles of object oriented programming, I'm confused about actionscript specific memory allocation and cleanup.

Comment: have you tried setting the movie clip variable to null?
`container = null`

Comment: Sorry, I think the problem I'm having is specific to the framework I'm using. Sorry for wasting your time, I appreciate the help.